# Create variable Array name to store a $_POST array

Tags: php

I'm processing a form with a lot of checkboxes. When the check if all the Required Fields are filled produces an error my form shows up again with the given Data prefilled (Text and Checkboxes). My Checkboxes can be assigned to 4 Different Topics, so I fill an array for each of this Topic.

so basically I take the $_POST data for each Topic and create an array out of it. If no Checkbox for a Topic is filled i have to create an empty array, because I need an array in order to make my Checkboxes getting prechecked (I use in_array to check if the checkboxvalue is set).

I'm quite new to php so I tried to make a function for this purpose (the regular way works fine).

My function:

```
function fill_checkboxarray($topic)
{
    if(!empty($_POST["".$topic.""]))
    {
        ${$topic} = $_POST["".$topic.""];
    }
    else
    {
        ${$topic} = array();
    }
    return ${$topic};
}
```

In my Script I set the name of the Topic that to the variable that is passed to my function:

```
$topic = "saunterstuetzt";
fill_checkboxarray($topic);

$topic = "sageplant";
fill_checkboxarray($topic);

$topic = "osunterstuetzt";
fill_checkboxarray($topic);

$topic = "osgeplant";
fill_checkboxarray($topic);
```

I get the following $_POST arrays:

```
$_POST["saunterstuetzt"]
$_POST["sageplant"]
$_POST["osunterstuetzt"]
$_POST["osgeplant"]
```

and need the following output: (arrays, either filled with POST data or empty)

```
$saunterstuetzt
$sageplant
$osunterstuetzt
$osgeplant
```

Somehow the variable array names don't work ... I get the error: "in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument", so i guess it doesn't create arrays ...

Thanks for your help in advance!
Languste

Comment: `in_array()` was not used in your example code. Please share more code.

Comment: Your function can be reduced to exactly this: `return !empty($_POST[$topic]) ? $_POST[$topic] : array();`. What you're doing is just a very complicated way to do that. It's also pointless since you're not doing anything with the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm quite new to php so I tried to make a function for this purpose.

You really shouldn't be using variable-variables.

Here's a cleaner, reusable approach:

```
function get_post_param($param, $default = null) {
  return empty($_POST[$param]) ? $default : $_POST[$param];
}

$saunterstuetzt = get_post_param("saunterstuetzt", array());
$sageplant = get_post_param("sageplant", array());
$osunterstuetzt = get_post_param("osunterstuetzt", array());
$osgeplant = get_post_param("osgeplant", array());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a variable with an specific name as return of a function!